# Python pip gcc error /Zl

Tags: python, gcc, pip

I am trying to use pip (or easy_install) to install mysql-python. I know it can be done by grabbing pre-compiled files, but I want pip or easy_install to work.

However, whenever I try to install using pip or easy_install, I am getting the following error:

**gcc: error: /Zl: No such file or directory**

From pip log:

```
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release


C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include -c _mysql.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\_mysql.o /Zl

gcc: error: /Zl: No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I installed MinGW for gcc, and have my Windows 8 path var set to include the path to the bin dir of it - C:\MinGW\bin;

Any advice much appreciated - I have had many previous issues, but eventually found a solution to previous problems here - [Python - Can't Install Packages: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683305/python-cant-install-packages-typeerror-unorderable-types-nonetype-str). But I am now stuck on this difficult issue.

Comment: `/Zl` I believe is targeted at Microsoft's compiler (MSC), so I guess that there is an issue that the target platform is confused with the compiler. File a bug report!

Answer (score 0):

Try this site:
http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries

This contains the unofficial binaries for MinGW GCC binary(not supported by MingGw) but its meant to integrate perfectly with python, even with the auto path updating. I tried it and was able to install and use pip fine...

hope this helps your GCC prob!

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but getting more errors: _mysql.c:2642: error: '_mysql_ResultObject' has no member named 'converter'

_mysql.c:2642: error: initializer element is not constant

_mysql.c:2642: error: (near initialization for '_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offset')

_mysql.c: In function '_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattr':

_mysql.c:2666: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'open'

gcc: /Zl: No such file or directory