# Python pip can't install pylint (Windows 8)

Tags: python, pip, package, installation, pylint

Whenever I try to install **pylint** or **flask** I get this error message. I tried to install a few other packages and some of them worked for example: **jsonpickle** or **numpy**. I have searched through stackoverflow and tried a few solutions that worked for others (like the --no-cache-dir) but they didn't work for me. I'm pretty new to python and really don't understand why I can't install these packages.

**My operating system:** *Windows 8*
**My python version:** *3.6.2*

I tried to reinstall python but it didn't work.
Here is the output I get when I try to install pylint.

````
PS C:\Users\my_user> pip install pylint --no-cache-dir
Collecting pylint
  Downloading pylint-1.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (644kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 645kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting astroid>=1.5.1 (from pylint)
  Downloading astroid-1.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (269kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 7.3MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\pyt
hon36-32\lib\site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe in c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
(from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: isort>=4.2.5 in c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\six
-1.10.0-py3.6.egg (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint)
Collecting wrapt (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint)
  Downloading wrapt-1.10.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: wrapt, astroid, pylint
  Running setup.py install for wrapt ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import s
etuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\my_user~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-f7qysct_\\wrapt\\setup.py';f=getattr(
tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" i
nstall --record C:\Users\my_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2qahpnfq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\arguments.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\my_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-f7qysct_\wrapt\setup.py", line 100, in <module>
        run_setup(with_extensions=True)
      File "C:\Users\my_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-f7qysct_\wrapt\setup.py", line 70, in run_setup
        setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_comman
ds
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_comman
d
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py
", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in
 run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_comman
d
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in r
un
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_comman
d
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\my_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-f7qysct_\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
        build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308,
in run
        force=self.force)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_
compiler
        return klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in
 __init__
        CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
      File "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in
 __init__
        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__fi
le__='C:\\Users\\my_user~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-f7qysct_\\wrapt\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(
__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users
\my_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2qahpnfq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" faile
d with error code 1 in C:\Users\my_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-f7qysct_\wrapt\```
````

**SOLUTION:**
Went to the python install path into the *C:\Python36-32\Lib\distutils* and edited the **distutils.cfg**.

**distutils.cfg - before**

```
[build]    
compiler=mingw32
```

**distutils.cfg - after**

```
[build]
#compiler=mingw32
compiler=msvc

[build_ext]
compiler=msvc
```

Comment: Do you also have python 2.x installed? Then you might want to run `pip3 install pylint` if pip is the one pointing to python 2.x

Comment: I have only python3 installed. I still tried it with ```pip3 install pylint``` but it didn't work. I got the same error as above.

Comment: Okay, the stack trace suggests, that there's a Problem with the CygwinCompiler. You could give a try updating setuptools first: `pip install --upgrade setuptools` You can get some information about windows compilers here: [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)

Comment: Tried it with ```pip install --upgrade setuptools``` first even restarted the computer (just in case) and after I tried ```pip install pylint --no-cache-dir``` I got the same error as before. (but the setuptools upgrade did work and it downloaded some stuff)

Comment: I found a question with a quite similar problem,  [maybe this is gonna help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37762479/2261273)

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I gonna flag this as duplicate now, as putting the answer here a second time wouldn't help anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Can't Install Packages: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683305/python-cant-install-packages-typeerror-unorderable-types-nonetype-str)