# Python 3.5 cythonizing not working to create DLL

Tags: python-3.x, cythonize

I am trying to create a DLL file (.pyd) using Python 3.5 and cython. I have the following files:

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name="Helloworld",
    ext_modules=cythonize("*.pyx"),
)
```

helloworld.pyx

```
print("Hello World!!")
```

To create `helloworld.pyx` file I created a `helloworld.py` file and renamed it to `.pyx`

I do the following to generate DLL file:

- open command prompt
- cd to directory with files
- run the command: python setup.py build_ext

I get the following error:

```
running build_ext
building 'Models.helloworld' extension
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The above steps is based on process for creating DLL files from the web. I tried looking up the error but haven't received any useful answer.

Edit:

I further checked install of cygwin and MinGW using this [link](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/appendix.html)

Now I get the following error:

```
C:\Model>python setup.py build_ext
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize("*.pyx"),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 307, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__
    if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()
```

Edit 2:
I tried the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683305/python-cant-install-packages-typeerror-unorderable-types-nonetype-str) but it doesn't work for my situation. I am using Windows 10 Pro, Python 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Can't Install Packages: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683305/python-cant-install-packages-typeerror-unorderable-types-nonetype-str)

Comment: I tried that solution already but it didn't help